# How to get chunk of 4 posts in my WP_Query loop WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am having a strange time in my development process, I have to create a filterable gallery from my portfolio post type. The design is some thing like, Every `second (2nd)` and `Eighth (8th)` post taking specific class name and that class is only those specific posts. How can I add class to every 2nd and 8th post in WordPress loop?

Posts sequence to add class will become some thing like `2nd, 8th, 10th, 18th, 20th, 28th` and so on ... How to add classes to above sequence in WordPress loop ?

Comment: Could [this topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225961/how-to-change-post-count-in-wordpress-loop/225981#225981) help?

Comment: @Dan, no Dan, he is looking for chunk array into specific pieces.

Comment: No, no I don't need chunk, I need just 2nd, 8th, 10th, 18th, 20th and 28th etc posts to add class to those posts etc ...